# How to put data in html instead of js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [easyautocomplete plugin](http://easyautocomplete.com/) and I have data something like that:

```
 data: [ {name: "Facebook", icon: "images/facebook.png"},
      {name: "Germany", icon: "images/germany.png"},
      {name: "Twitter", icon: "images/twitter.png"}],
```

but I need to use this data with html not jquery..for example like that:

```
<ul>
<li>Facebook <img src="images/facebook.png"></li>
<li>Germany <img src="images/germany.png"></li>
</ul>
```

and my working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
    data: [ 
        {name: "Facebook", icon: "images/facebook.png"},
        {name: "Germany", icon: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/finalflags/16/Germany-Flag.png"},
        {name: "Twitter", icon: "images/twitter.png",url: "http://www.google.com"},
        {name: "Linkedin", icon: "images/linkedin.png"},
        {name: "Google Plus", icon: "images/google_plus.png"},
        {name: "Vimeo", icon: "images/vimeo.png"}
    ],
    getValue: 'name',
    list: {
      match: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    template: {
      type: "iconLeft",
      fields: {
        iconSrc: "icon"
      }
    }
  };

  $("#social").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type='text' id='social'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly? You want to output to HTML after you made a selection in the autocomplete suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Custom Template for easyautocomplete. Check out this link: http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-template-custom.

Comment: @Mary yes exactly you understand what I want

Comment: So you want to display all choices in a list or just display the selected option ?

Comment: @recruit_man Check my answer below – this should do what you want.

Comment: Yes alexis that's right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React to the `onClickEvent` you can find in the [Docs](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-trigger-event). Then find the data of the current selection, build your HTML and add it to the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {
    data: [ {name: "Facebook", icon: "images/facebook.png"},
    {name: "Germany", icon: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/finalflags/16/Germany-Flag.png"},
    {name: "Twitter", icon: "images/twitter.png",url: "http://www.google.com"},
    {name: "Linkedin", icon: "images/linkedin.png"},
    {name: "Google Plus", icon: "images/google_plus.png"},
    {name: "Vimeo", icon: "images/vimeo.png"}],
    getValue: 'name',
    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        },
        onClickEvent: function() {
            var $newItem = $('<li />'),
                data = $("#social").getSelectedItemData();

            $newItem.text(data.name + ' ')
                .append($('<img />').attr('src', data.icon));

            $('#selection-here').append($newItem);
        }
    },
    template: {
        type: "iconLeft",
        fields: {
            iconSrc: "icon"
        }
    }
};

$("#social").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type='text' id='social'>
<ul id="selection-here"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks..my structure is like this now: <ul id="selection-here">
<li><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/finalflags/16/Germany-Flag.png"> Kuveyt</li>
</ul>

but when I search nothing matched why ? and why I see result on default

Comment: as @Alexis said I want to display all choices in a list that was my question actually